# PowerShell Get-AdGroupmember doen't work for some groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I am trying to execute the below PowerShell command. Its giving proper results for some AD groups, but "Cannot find an object with identity xxxx under region.company.com" for few groups. I'm looping the below command over a list of AD groups in the same domain (I can see the those groups throwing error in the Active Directory web interface. So those AD groups are actually there under the same $domain - yyy) I've obviously checked the spelling, syntax etc multiple times. (In fact, the script works perfectly for all the remaining domains).

```
$domain = "region.company.com"
$group = "xxxx"
Get-ADGroupMember -server $domain -identity $group | select name,distinguishedname
```

I am new to PowerShell and banging my head over this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Here, I'm passing the group name in $group. I also tried to use distinguished name instead of group's name, and it threw same error for ALL the groups, not some!

Edit: I've corrected the typo errors and included few more details on the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Are you sure the cmdlet you are having problems with is `Get-EDGroupMember` and not `Get-ADGroupMember`?  2. Are you sure you should be using `:server` instead of `-server`? 3. What is the ***exact*** error message, in full, that you are getting?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Sorry for the typo errors. I've corrected them and included few more details on the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you actually dealing with ps2? if not, then please remove that tag.

Comment: May try running powershell as administrator. We’ve seen that make a difference.

Comment: @Doug Maurer, tried as admin, makes no difference.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, tag removed

Comment: @Sheila - thank you! [*grin*]

Comment: Are the groups returned from Get-ADGroup? E.g. Get-ADGroup -server ad.example.com  -LDAPFilter "(&(cn=MyGroup))" And, if so, can you pipe the output of Get-ADGroup to Get-ADGroupMember? e.g. Get-ADGroup? E.g. Get-ADGroup -server ad.example.com  -LDAPFilter "(&(cn=MyGroup))" | Get-ADGroupMember -server ad.example.com

Comment: Can you show us such a group name that make `Get-ADGroupMember` fail? Does it contain diacritics of slashes maybe?